# rails-react-boilerplate: Webpack not compiling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack

### Introduction

I trying to run rails-react-boilerplate, everything goes fine, but at the end of installation (bundle install, yarn install, rake db:create ..), command with webpack simple not working. There is a link on github repository: [rails-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/giannisp/rails-react-boilerplate).

### Error

After this command `npm run webpack` I get this error:

```
openssl config failed: error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process
> rails-react-boilerplate@1.0.0 webpack D:\code\portfolio\liftProgress
> ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --colors

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! rails-react-boilerplate@1.0.0 webpack: 
`./node_modules/webpack/bin/webp                                                                                        
ack.js --progress --colors`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the rails-react-boilerplate@1.0.0 webpack script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.                                                                                    

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Derid\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-12-
30T07_27_37_                                                                                        
058Z-debug.log
openssl config failed: error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process
```

where I think main problem is:

```
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

.. but I am at one's wits' end .. very thanks for your guidance and help!:)

Comment: I can't run too so then I found this https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails. It so simple.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Windows issue, you can try omitting the `./` from the actual command on the `package.json` file.

Actually after doing some research, including the node executable should work cross-platform:

`"webpack": "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --colors",`

Comment: `'node_modules' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @OristTimemaker I have updated the answer, and the repo.

Comment: When I change this path, I got message: `System can't found stated path` .. After I also tried yarn command: `yarn run webpack-watch`, there wasn't error, but also nothing happened (folder dist wasn't created, css and js files too ..).

Comment: @OristTimemaker Can you please pull the latest from `master` branch and try again? All scripts have been updated to include the `node` executable.

Comment: I'm sorry, but problem is maybe at my side .. I pulled the changes, now without error, but scripts still doing nothing .. maybe I should try Linux instead Windows for programming

Comment: @OristTimemaker The output path is `public/dist`. No files in there? Maybe try Window 10 bash shell instead of the Windows command line.

Comment: I installed nodejs and npm on Window 10 bash shell, and run the command .. but same behaviour at windows/git bash. I don't get it, but app which was created with `create-react-app` works.